# UIButton and Swipe Gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIView` with two `UIButton`s on each side (left and right) and a `UIImageView` in the center.  A tap on either button will change the `UIImageView` and that works.  I want the ability swipe across the `UIView` as well and it change `UIImageView`.  Right now, you have to swipe on the `UIImageView` itself since the `UIButton`s are catching the input.

I'd like to be able to perform a swipe anywhere on the containing `UIView` and it performs the transition.  Is there a way to forward touch events such that a swipe can trigger an action, but any other touch is forwarded to the proper subviews?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `delaysTouchesBegan` to `YES` on the gesture recognizer, which will make it only forward touch events to subviews if a gesture is not recognized.

Answer (score 2):

How do you currently have the UIButtons set up to receive the input?  Make sure that the selector you are hooking up the UIButton is hooked up with "Touch Up Inside".  This should ensure that a swipe that begins on one of the buttons does not actually activate the button (assuming the user swipes all the way off the button).