# iOS gestureRecognizer not handled subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

i have the following problem: in my iphone app i have a `UIView` that holds 0 to several subviews. Those subviews may overflow the parent and therefore be hidden and all of them are `UIButtons`. I added a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the `UIView` to move the buttons around which works great. However it only works when the gesture is done on background, the `UIButton`s interfere with the gesture recognizer.

How i can i pass the gesture through? Btw. i still need the tap of the Buttons.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I tried to add the gesture recognizer to the UIButtons too, but it is not triggered... Although performing the swipe gesture prevents the UIButton from going to highlighted state it doesn't trigger the gesture. I added `setDelaysTouchesBegan:YES` as suggested in [UIButton and Swipe Gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424373/uibutton-and-swipe-gesture). That's how i do it right now:

```
UIButton *breadcrumb = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[breadcrumb setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Next"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[breadcrumb setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[breadcrumb.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f]];
[breadcrumb sizeToFit];
[breadcrumb setTag:level];


UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[gr setDelegate:self];
[gr setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[gr setDelaysTouchesBegan:YES];
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:gr];
[breadcrumb addGestureRecognizer:gr];
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have now subclassed UIButton and initilizing it now like so: `[BreadcrumbButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]`. In the initializer i added the button itsself as a listener to all touch events `[self addTarget:self action:@selector(eventReceiver:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];` to inspect whats going on.

```
- (void)eventReceiver:(UIButton *)btn {
    NSLog(@"Reveived event: %@ ---------------", btn);

    for(UIGestureRecognizer *gr in ev.gestureRecognizers) {
        NSLog(@"Gesture: %@", gr);
    }
}
```

What i see is that a) the button has just one gesture recognizer added and b) that this `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` jumps to state `Possible` during swipe but does not forward to its delegate methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to subclass the UIButton and over ride the tap delegate callback and forward this call to whatever is handling a UISwipeGestureRecognizer. Unless you add the gesture recognizer on the UIButton, it will always call it's touch handler before the view behind it. You can also explicitly tell the button to not handle it's touch events thus passing the touch event down the chain (via userInteractionEnabled), but as you've already stated you do not want this. The best way to go about this would be by creating a subclass of UIButton and handling the touch events there and/or forwarding the events using delegation. Pressing the button is a touch event, so you may just want to add a tap gesture recognizer to the button and call the IBAction from that and then have the swipegesturerecognizer forward a delegate call.

Comment: Thanks i'll try that, although i wanted to avoid that. I thought maybe the swipe gesture could be handled differently as it does not trigger the tap on the `UIButton`.

Comment: Yea, sorry. Due to the way that touch events are handled in their prioritized order, there isn't a way to get around this without adding a gesture on top of the UIButton or forwarding the touch events. Touch events start at the up most item in the hierarchy (with gestures taking first priority) and then they trickle their way down. It doesn't work in reverse.

Comment: I tried now to add the UISwipeGesturerecognizer to the buttons as i am creating them programatically anyway. But it still doesn't get called. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the buttons large enough to get a swipe gesture? If they are not, the gesture will never be triggered. If worse comes to worse, and you can't figure out how to add the gestures in a way you need, you can always add an invisible view on top with the gesture recognizers onto of them. When the gestures are triggered, you can perform a hit test on the UIButtons to see if those are being touched. If the buttons are not being touched, ignore the gestures. If the buttons are touched and it's a tap gesture, trigger the UIButton action, if the buttons are touched and it's a swipe, move the buttons.

Comment: Yes buttons are large enough. I updated my question with the code i use to add the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to my buttons. However i found out, that if i initialize the recognizer with a target (`initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)`) the `handleSwipe:` method gets called, while the delegate methods of UIGestureRecognizer are not being called. Strange.

Comment: Why are you adding the gesture recognizer to two things via: [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:gr];
[breadcrumb addGestureRecognizer:gr];. I'll create a demo project when I have some time tonight and try to post it up on github for you to take a look at.

Comment: Here's an example project. Hopefully this should help you. https://github.com/thegamingart/GestureDummyProject   Be sure to check the storyboard settings for the gestures as well.

Comment: I also wanted to ask are you sure that you should be using a swipe gesture for moving the buttons. Just wanted to make sure you're not expecting more than one callback regarding the gesture (which a pan gesture will provide).

Comment: Thanks so much for helping. I feel kind of stupid right now, because i completely missunderstood some concepts and in retrospect i wonder how this could have happened. However your test project got me to the right track. Its embarassing but I somehow thought touches[Began/Moved/...] were swipe gesture callbacks... Anyway the solution is as you pointed out a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. Now everythings works fine...

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you found the answer. Points are always appreciated :p

Comment: If you help me once again and tell me how i can give you points? Accept your answer? If so can you put "use a UIPanGestureRecognizer dumba**" in it :D